# Custom Translation of Backend in Magento 2 - path of the translate.csv?

Tags: magento2, module, custom, backend, localisation

I am familiar with translations in Magento 1 and found out also how translations in M2 work for the frontend. My questions is where to do my translation for my own custom module for the backend. Is there also a translation.csv and where should I put it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2, translations file is saved in `/vendor/magento/<module-modulename>/i18n` folder.

For example, if you want to modify translation for word related to **checkout module**, it could be saved in `/vendor/magento/module-checkout/i18n/<locale-folder>` folder.

You can copy locale's csv file from `/vendor/magento/module-checkout/i18n` folder to `app/code/Magento/module-checkout/i18n` directory.

Please let me know if some thing is unclear.

Comment: I tried same but not working in my case. Do I need to create registartion.php for same?

Comment: No @RanjitShinde, there is no need to create registration.php. You may need to compile and deploy static content.

Comment: I compile and deployed but its not working

Answer (score 0):

app/code/Vendor/Module/i18n/en_US.csv

To change label:

```
Quantity,"Quantity Available"
```

[image]